# In Sencha, Ext or just javascript how do you format and display a number as money?

Tags: extjs

Ideally, I would define a new Ext field type called moneyfield that extends Number that I can use anywhere in my application to display numbers with a $ and commas.  I'm surprised Sencha hasn't already provided this for us.  Has anyone created such a class?

Answer (score 1):

Ext.util.Format.usMoney() formats a number to US currency - you could probably use those in field renderers etc. If you want something more generic, check out Ext.util.Format.currency()

Comment: This worked for my list page where the field is a column.  Still need a way to deal with textfields on a form.

Comment: Override its setValue() method.